# loading a lib from lua

Tags: c++, lua

when loading a .dll file from lua it gives me this error:

```
loop or previous error loading module 'wildcard'
```

whats wrong?
@edit:
@lhf: ive changed the filename but now its giving me these errors:

```
> dofile("_test.lua")
```

_test.lua:1: module 'wildcard' not found:
        no field package.preload['wildcard']
        no file '.\wildcard.lua'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\lua\wildcard.lua'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\lua\wildcard\init.lua'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\wildcard.lua'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\wildcard\init.lua'
        no file '.\wildcard.dll'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\wildcard.dll'
        no file 'D:\luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc6\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        _test.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
>

Comment: Without code, how the hell are we supposed to know?

Comment: do you want the C code or the lua code? I'm sry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
package.loaded.wildcard = false
```

See [refman](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaded) which describes the `package` table.

Comment: now it works but its giving me nil values on the functions in the .dll

Comment: Perhaps the DLL is defective, or wasn't written for (your version of) Lua. There is no way to tell from the information you've provided. I see you have used a C++ tag; the DLL should have a C interface, not mangled C++ names.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a `wildcard.lua` file with

```
require"wildcard"
```

and expect that this will load `wildcard.dll`. It won't because priority is given to Lua modules, hence your loop.